# Javascript Search word in String not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How i can search word in string ?

**Example**

```
var string="Stackoverflow is the BEST";
if i search 'BEST' it should return true
if i search 'is' it should return true
if i search 'bEST' it should return true
if i search 'BES' it should return false
if i search 'flow' it should return false
```

I have tried the following:

```
match()
search()
indexof()
```

How i can do it? thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/FxV53/3/

Comment: so u basicall want to match whole word.. ?

Comment: Split by space, loop, compare?

Comment: i am willing to match exact work not character

Comment: @ elclanrs ,basically i am willing to make like query but its should match with word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b` is a word boundary character in a regular expression. `/i` is ignore case. Replace best with your search word.

```
var string="Stackoverflow is the BEST";
var searchText = "Stackoverflow";
var re = new RegExp("\\b"+searchText+"\\b",'i');
if ( re.test(string)){
  alert('match');
}else {
  alert('not match');
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FxV53/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex check. Google for word boundaries to learn more about them.

```
/\bbest\b/i.test("Stackoverflow is the BEST")
```

`\b` is a word boundary character in a regular expression. `/i` is ignore case. Replace `best` with your search word.

Comment: How i can user with variable instead of /\bbest\b/i?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit more verbose, but why not something like:

```
var exists = function (content, q) {
    var result = content.split(" ").filter(function(item) {
        return item.toLowerCase() === q.toLowerCase(); 
    });
    return result.length > 0;
};
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FxV53/6/).

Answer (score -1):

use `.test()`

```
var string="Stackoverflow is the BEST";
var result= /s/i.test(string);
alert(result);
```